# How to set a String ViewModel property on ReadioButton Check usin WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am new to WPF and here I am trying to set a simple string property of my viewModel when a particular radio button is checked on my window.

```
class ViewModel
{
  string LanguageSettings {get;set;}
}
```

XAML looks like following:

```
 <RadioButton Name="OptionEnglish" GroupName="LanguageOptions" IsChecked="{Binding LanguageSettings, Converter={StaticResource Converter}, ConverterParameter=English}" Content="English" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="760" />
        <RadioButton Name="OptionChinese" GroupName="LanguageOptions" IsChecked="{Binding LanguageSettings, Converter={StaticResource Converter}, ConverterParameter=Chinese}" Content="Chinese" />
```

I have implemented the IValueConverted which looks like below:

```
 public class BoolInverterConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        #region IValueConverter Members

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is bool)
            {
                return !(bool)value;
            }
            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is bool)
            {
                return !(bool)value;
            }
            return value;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Probably I am not properly understanding the utility of IValueConverter. I think if I change it appropriately it might work.

All I want here is that when English is selected I want Language Settings to be set as English and same for Chinese. Is there any simple way to do it?  is there any straightforward way to set that property?

So i do have two options

1.Change my BoolConverterImplementation
2. Find another easier way to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: What would you expect to put into a string with when the RadioButton is checked? BTW that is not a property that is a field. WPF does not bind to fields

Comment: @HighCore Actually it's an incomplete line, we can't say what it is.

Comment: @HighCore : When RadioButton is checked I do want my LanguageSettings property to be set to the radiobutton's content. Btw I changed my sample to have property not a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into implementing IValueConverter.  Below is a starting example for what I believe you are looking for:

```
public class StringMatchConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value,Type targetType,object parameter,CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == parameter;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value,Type targetType,object parameter,CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
<!-- Somewhere in resources -->
<conv:StringMatchConverter x:Key="Conv" />

<!-- Somewhere in application -->
<RadioButton Name="OptionEnglish" GroupName="LanguageOptions" IsChecked="{Binding LanguageSettings,Converter={StaticResource Conv}, ConverterParameter=English}" Content="English" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="760" />
<RadioButton Name="OptionChinese" GroupName="LanguageOptions" IsChecked="{Binding LanguageSettings,Converter={StaticResource Conv}, ConverterParameter=Chinese}" Content="Chinese" />
```

Comment: I think i have done something similar. I changed my question. May be you have give better idea from it.

Comment: The value being passed into Convert is the string, not a Boolean.  Did the converter above not help out?

Answer (score 2):

An approach that does not require a converter:

```
<RadioButton Content="Chinese" IsChecked="{Binding IsChinese}"/>
<RadioButton Content="English" IsChecked="{Binding IsEnglish}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class LanguageSelectorViewModel
{
    private bool _isChinese;
    private bool _isEnglish;

    public bool IsChinese
    {
        get { return _isChinese; }
        set
        {
            _isChinese = value;

            if (value)
                SelectedLanguage = "Chinese";
        }
    }

    public bool IsEnglish
    {
        get { return _isEnglish; }
        set
        {
            _isEnglish = value;

            if (value)
                SelectedLanguage = "English";
        }
    }

    public string SelectedLanguage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Missing the if (...) arround the setter if Selected language so that it don;t set when it is false

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but if I understand you correct you maybe could use a [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to create an attached property:

```
public class MyAttachedProperty
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedToStrProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsCheckedToStr", typeof (string), typeof (MyAttachedProperty), new PropertyMetadata(default(string,IsCheckedToStr)))

        private static void IsCheckedToStr(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton radio = d as RadioButton;
            radio.Checked+=radio_Checked;

        }

        private static void radio_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton radio = sender as RadioButton;

            if (radio.IsChecked == true)
            {
                SetIsCheckedToStr(radio, radio.Content.ToString());
            }
        }

    public static void SetIsCheckedToStr(UIElement element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsCheckedToStrProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetIsCheckedToStr(UIElement element)
    {
        return (string) element.GetValue(IsCheckedToStrProperty);
    }
}
```

And then you can use it in your xaml like this:

```
<RadioButton Name="OptionEnglish" GroupName="LanguageOptions" local:MyAttachedProperty.IsCheckedStr="{Binding LanguageSettings}" Content="English" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="760" />
<RadioButton Name="OptionChinese" GroupName="LanguageOptions" local:MyAttachedProperty.IsCheckedStr="{Binding LanguageSettings}" Content="Chinese" />
```